# Can Telegram bots search for user contacts?

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to add a feature for my Telegram inline bot to allow searching for user contacts. I even can see `InlineQueryResultContact` among available types for sending inline query results. However, I do not understand how a bot can access user contact list. Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for us (Telegram users) bots can't search for user contacts. They may send other's contacts if programmed this way.